# How can I concatenate the current timestamp to a piped input on bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command

I want to use the ts or awk (gawk) command to concatenate timestamps on piped inputs. However, the start time of the program is fixed. I would like to concatenate the timestamp of the moment when input occurs rather than a fixed time.

command here

```
top | grep compiz |ts '%H:%M:%S' | awk '{print $1, $11}' > cpu_timestamp.txt
```

output here(push 'q' to quit the top)

```
16:23:04 37.5
16:23:04 4.0
16:23:04 4.0
16:23:04 3.7
16:23:04 2.3
16:23:04 1.7
```

but, I want like this

```
16:23:04 37.5
16:23:05 4.0
16:23:06 4.0
16:23:07 3.7
16:23:08 2.3
16:23:09 1.7
```

Comment: The output expected and one above look the same. Can you explain a bit more on the requirement?

Comment: The top command outputs the results periodically. I want to output an additional timestamp with this periodic result. The above result is displayed only for one time, but the bottom is the result I want, and a different time is output each time.

Comment: Instead of `top | grep compiz` you could use `ps -C compiz ho pcpu`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with command "bash"

```
top -b | grep --line-buffered "bash" | ts '%H:%M:%S' | awk '{print $1, $11}'
```

Output:

```
09:52:58 0.1
09:52:58 0.0
09:52:58 0.1
09:53:01 0.1
09:53:01 0.0
09:53:01 0.1
09:53:04 0.1
09:53:04 0.0
09:53:04 0.1
...
```

I used Linux with `top: procps version 3.2.8`, `GNU grep 2.6.3` and `GNU Awk 3.1.7`.

Comment: --line-buffered is the secret!

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what `ts` does but to print the current time for each line of input with `gawk` you just call strftime() and you never need grep when you're using awk so I suspect all you need with GNU awk is:

```
top | awk '/compiz/{strftime("%H:%M:%S"), print $1, $11}' > cpu_timestamp.txt
```

You might need to add a call to the UNIX tool `stdbuf` somewhere in the pipeline if buffering proves to be an issue but if your previous pipeline worked then I'd expect this one to too.